# No inicializar a ninguna fecha en DateRangePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

la pregunta es sencilla pero llevo tiempo sin saber solucionarla:
Tengo un input de fecha pero no quiero que se inicialice, o sea, quiero que no muestre ninguna fecha si el usuario no ha elegido ninguna.
Haga lo que haga, la fecha se incializa, incluso poniendo value="". He intentado cambiar varias opciones pero ninguna funciona.

```js
$('input[name="date_expiration"]').daterangepicker({
  singleDatePicker: true,
  showDropdowns: true,
  locale: {
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    cancelLabel: 'Cancelar',
    applyLabel: 'Aplicar'
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css"/>

<input type="text" name="date_expiration" class="form-control" value="" id="id_date_expiration">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js" integrity="sha256-nQLuAZGRRcILA+6dMBOvcRh5Pe310sBpanc6+QBmyVM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
```

La documentación no dice nada al respecto. https://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: no es mejor cambiarle el tipo de input de text a date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes asignarle un evento con el método **`.on()`** de JQuery y luego usar **`focus`** para decir que al hacer clic en el input, ocurra las instrucciones de adentro, ejemplo:

```js
$('input[name="date_expiration"]').on("focus", function(){
  $(this).daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    locale: {
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
      cancelLabel: 'Cancelar',
      applyLabel: 'Aplicar'
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css"/>

<input type="text" name="date_expiration" class="form-control" value="" id="id_date_expiration">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js" integrity="sha256-nQLuAZGRRcILA+6dMBOvcRh5Pe310sBpanc6+QBmyVM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ha funcionado perféctamente. Gracias.

Comment: Un placer ayudarle, saludos.